# Запрос из PHP на вебсервис SOAP

Tags: php, xml, soap

Вот появилась задача с API курьерской службы, у которых вебсервис работает на SOAP.
Нужно сформировать запрос XML на PHP. Через POSTMAN запрос проходит и всё ок. Вот только не могу понять как правильно сформировать запрос в PHP  скрипте. Буду очень благодарен любой помощи.
Пример запроса:

````
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pos="http://webservices.kazpost.kz/postratesws">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <pos:GetAddrLetterRequest>
  <pos:Key>69a316asdas1231267dc5b3</pos:Key>
  <pos:AddrInfo>
   <!--Optional:-->
   <pos:RcpnName>Тест</pos:RcpnName>
   <pos:RcpnPhone>87071234567</pos:RcpnPhone>
   <pos:RcpnIndex>050000</pos:RcpnIndex>
   <pos:RcpnCity>Алматы</pos:RcpnCity>
   <pos:RcpnStreet>Богенбай</pos:RcpnStreet>
   <pos:RcpnHouse>1</pos:RcpnHouse>
   <pos:SndrBIN>098765432121</pos:SndrBIN>
   <pos:SndrName>отправитель</pos:SndrName>
   <pos:SndrPhone>87071234567</pos:SndrPhone>
   <pos:SndrIndex>010000</pos:SndrIndex>
   <pos:SndrCity>Нур-Султан</pos:SndrCity>
   <pos:SndrStreet>Кунаева</pos:SndrStreet>
   <pos:SndrHouse>20</pos:SndrHouse>
   <pos:Weight>1</pos:Weight>
   <pos:ProductCode>P118</pos:ProductCode>
   <pos:Marks>
    <pos:Mark>ReturnAfter</pos:Mark>
   </pos:Marks>
   <pos:SendMethod>1</pos:SendMethod>
   <pos:MailCtg>1</pos:MailCtg>
  </pos:AddrInfo>
 </pos:GetAddrLetterRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через CURL, как вариант.
В Postman есть волшебная кнопочка "Code". Если кликнуть, появится список с различными ЯП. Выбирайте PHP Curl и будет вам счастье :)

Comment: Вот это новость! Я не знал про эту волшебную кнопку :) Спасибо большое! Всё получилось :-)

Comment: @Yessey так примите ж ответ)

Comment: Принял. Спасибо :-) Еще один момент. А как передать переменную внутри XML, в параметре CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ?

Comment: Просто вставьте в строку переменную:
$key = "123456";
$xml = "<soapenv:Body><pos:GetAddrLetterRequest><pos:Key>{$key}</pos:Key>";

Comment: Работает! Теперь пытаюсь ответ в XML перевести в JSON или в PHP массив через $xml = simplexml_load_string($response); получаю пустой массив var_dump-ом.

Comment: @Yessey, попробуйте через DOMDocument::loadXML: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadxml.php

Answer (score 0):

Теперь пытаюсь ответ в XML перевести в JSON или в PHP массив через $xml = simplexml_load_string($response); получаю пустой массив var_dump-ом.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header />
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:GetAddrLetterResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservices.kazpost.kz/postratesws">
            <ns2:AddrLetPdf>
                
                //BASE64 code//
                
            </ns2:AddrLetPdf>
            <ns2:Barcode>ES000081548KZ</ns2:Barcode>
            <ns2:ResponseInfo>
                <ns2:ResponseGenTime>2020-07-21T10:14:57.405+06:00</ns2:ResponseGenTime>
                <ns2:ResponseCode>0</ns2:ResponseCode>
                <ns2:ResponseText>Принято успешно!</ns2:ResponseText>
            </ns2:ResponseInfo>
        </ns2:GetAddrLetterResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```